# Getting certificates from PKCS11 Smartcard without PIN/password

Tags: java, pkcs#11

Abstract: when using JCA over PKCS11 over OpenSC, the PIN is requested when extracting certificates.

I have got an application that needs to sign using a smartcard. The smartcard is supported by OpenSC, so I am using the Java-built-in pkcs11 wrapper provider to use it. For functional reasons, I need to obtain the certificates in the card without a PIN requested. If the user finally signs, then, of course, the PIN is needed.

I see I can do it from command line without providing a PIN:

```
pkcs11-tool --module C:\WINDOWS\system32\opensc-pkcs11.dll -r -a 50-MDS_Signature -y cert -o p.cer
Using slot 1 with a present token (0x1)
```

So far, so good.

The documentation from Oracle clearly says "The builder will prompt for a password as needed using the previously configured callback handler" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Login). However, my code does always request the pin as son as I call `KeyStore ks0 = ksbuilder0.getKeyStore();` even while only extracting public info (such as certificates).

Follows an extract of the code:

```
private static final String PKCS11_LIB = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\opensc-pkcs11.dll";
private static final String NAME = "OpenSCpkcs11";
private static final String SLOT = "1";
private static final String PIN = "11111111";
private static final String ALIAS = "myCert";

[...]

private static CallbackHandler myCallbackHandler = new CallbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
            if (callback instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                PasswordCallback passwordCallback = (PasswordCallback) callback;
                System.out.println(passwordCallback.getPrompt() + PIN);
                passwordCallback.setPassword(PIN.toCharArray());
            }
        }
    }
};

[...]

String configString = "name = "
  + NAME.replace(' ', '_')
  + "\n"
  + "library = "
  + PKCS11_LIB
  + "\n slot = "
  + SLOT
  + " "
  + "\n attributes = compatibility \n"
  + "attributes(*,*,*)=\n{\nCKA_TOKEN=true\nCKA_LOCAL=true\n}";
ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    configString.getBytes());
SunPKCS11 pkcs11Provider0 = new SunPKCS11(configStream);
pkcs11Provider0.login(null, myCallbackHandler);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider0);
KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection chp = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(
    myCallbackHandler);
KeyStore.Builder ksbuilder0 = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance(
    "PKCS11", pkcs11Provider0, chp);
KeyStore ks0 = ksbuilder0.getKeyStore();
X509Certificate cert0 = (X509Certificate) ks0.getCertificate(ALIAS);
// System.out.println("Cert " + cert0.toString());
Principal p = cert0.getSubjectDN();
System.out.println("I am: " + cert0.getSubjectDN().getName());
```

It results on:

```
Contraseña de la tarjeta de claves PKCS11 [SunPKCS11-OpenSCpkcs11]: 11111111
2014-01-16 17:48:11.275 cannot lock memory, sensitive data may be paged to disk
I am: CN=pepe perez, SURNAME=pepe, L=qwerty
```

As you can see, the password is requested before the certificate is got. By means of debugging I can see that the password is requested in the line `KeyStore ks0 = ksbuilder0.getKeyStore();`

Any idea? Is there no way to configure it as I want? Any further idea or test?

Furthermore: do you know of any other way to access smartcards, for example directly through a JAVA2OpenSC wrapper or the like?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there was no solution using JCA. The final solution was to directly attack the PKCS11 driver. I have used jacknji11 (https://github.com/joelhockey/jacknji11) and the PKCS11 spec (http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-standard.htm).

Comment: (Notice I am the original writter of the question). The answer from Plasmen Valisev seems a good approach. I have not marked it as accepted answer because I have not personally tested it, but it seems a very reasonable approach and is much simpler than my solution.

Answer (score 9):

**SOLVED**

I have found a way to get the public certificate from the smart card.

```
    String pkcs11Config = "name = SmartCard\nlibrary = /path/to/libraby.so";
    ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
    Provider prov = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(confStream);
    Security.addProvider(prov);
    KeyStore cc = null;
    String pin = "";
    try {
        cc = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",prov);
        KeyStore.PasswordProtection pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pin.toCharArray());
        cc.load(null ,  pp.getPassword() );
        Enumeration aliases = cc.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object alias = aliases.nextElement();
            try {
                X509Certificate cert0 = (X509Certificate) cc.getCertificate(alias.toString());
                System.out.println("I am: " + cert0.getSubjectDN().getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The KeyStore.load() should be provided with PaswordProtection object with empty pin.
This allows me to read the public certificate and extract the data from it.

I have tested this with 3 different types of smart cards and it is working on all of them

Comment: `error: package sun.security.pkcs11 is not visible
        Provider sunPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11();
                                             ^
  (package sun.security.pkcs11 is declared in module jdk.crypto.cryptoki, which is not in the module graph)`

I get this error when I try your code :'(

Answer (score 0):

Well, what i've once done was something like

```
    Provider prov = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11("pkcs.cfg");
    Security.addProvider(prov);
    KeyStore cc = null;
    try {
        cc = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
        cc.load(null, null);
        cc.getCertificate("CITIZEN AUTHENTICATION CERTIFICATE")
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The pkcs.cfg is a file pointing to the "libpteidpkcs11.so" library, and you should be able to adapt it to your code. Mine reads:

```
name = SmartCard
library = /usr/local/lib/libpteidpkcs11.so
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not work: `load(null, null)` raises `javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: no password provided, and no callback handler available for retrieving password`

Comment: try adding a char[] as the password to the load method

Comment: EDIT: your problem was that you didn't want to request a password, right. I'm not sure then. With the portuguese citizen cards, this works. maybe your cards have different arquitectures or your lib is not appropriate

Comment: the card itself allows getting the certificates without password (see the example with opensc pkcs11-tool in the question). I guess the Java JCA wrapping is the one that is causing it, either because I missconfigured it, or because it does not support such behaviour (the doc says it does, though), or something else that I am not understanding. Maybe the "attributes" section? Do you have a sample code of how to initialize it for such portuguesse cards?

Comment: I did exactly what i have shown you here and it works. Don't know what could be wrong. Maybe someone with more experience can figure it out

Comment: Thanks. However, the content of pkcs.cfg may be important. Would it be possible for you to paste it here?

Comment: I did. It's the bottom 2 lines of my post

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have a section attributes{} so I thought it was only an excerpt. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is use [IAIK PKCS#11 Wrapper](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/products/core-crypto-toolkits/pkcs11-wrapper/). JavaDoc [here](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/index.html). Example code below.

```
/**
 * list certificates
 * 
 * @param module - PKCS#11 (.dll or .so) module path
 * for example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ENCARD\enigmap11.dll"
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void listCertificates(String module) throws Exception {
    Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance(module);
    pkcs11Module.initialize(null);
    
    Slot[] slotsWithToken = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT);
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    
    for(Slot s: slotsWithToken) {
        Session session = s.getToken().openSession(Token.SessionType.SERIAL_SESSION, Token.SessionReadWriteBehavior.RO_SESSION, null, null);
        session.findObjectsInit(new X509PublicKeyCertificate());
        Object[] objects = null;
        while((objects = session.findObjects(1)).length > 0) {
            for(Object c: objects) {
                X509PublicKeyCertificate cert = (X509PublicKeyCertificate) c;
                byte[] certValue = cert.getValue().getByteArrayValue();
                Certificate cc = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certValue));
                if(cc instanceof X509Certificate) {
                    X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) cc;
                    log.info(x509.getNotBefore() + " - " + x509.getNotAfter());
                }                       
            }
        }
        session.findObjectsFinal();
    }           
    pkcs11Module.finalize(null);
}
```