# itext- can't sign pdf with another usb token

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pkcs#11

so i wrote a programme that can sign pdf using usb token and everything is fine, i tried to sign using another token from the same company(same provider) but different style(no finger print) and i cant even get the login window to show up.
this is the error i get:

```
 SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: load failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:763)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: no password provided, and no callback handler available for retrieving password
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1184)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:849)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:751)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167927/getting-certificates-from-pkcs11-smartcard-without-pin-password

Comment: @eightShirt thanks. .... i added char[] pass = "12345678".toCharArray();
and ks.load(null,pass);
BUT thats not what i need , with the first token i didnt have to set the pin from code ... it will simply show up a login window ...i need to do the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String pass="";
KeyStore.PasswordProtection pp = new keyStore.PasswordProtection(pass.toCharArray());
    ks.load(null ,  pp.getPassword() );
```

that solved my problem

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution to your own problem. This will help others in the future.